# Blocking firebase analytics events doesnt work with GTM

Tags: android, events, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics in my app, and i track events like this:

```
public static String EVENT_MAIN_ACTIVITY_OPEN = "EVENT_MAIN_ACTIVITY_OPEN";
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();        
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(EVENT_MAIN_ACTIVITY_OPEN, bundle);
```

These events are displayed normally in debug-view mode and in normal mode in firecase console.

Now, i want to block some events using GTM, without code fixes. How can i make this? 
There are my variables, tags and triggers in GTM:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I added GTM-xxxxx.json into main/assets/containers folder.
But event doesnt block (i track events view degub-view mode in firebase). So, how to resolve this?